# How solve instance of error when call method?

Tags: php

I have class with constants. How i can be sure actionWithParams() will get current class constants? Now i got *"instance of"* error:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    const PARAM_1 = 1;
    const PARAM_2 = 2;

    protected $plans;


    // ..

    public function actionWithParam(MyClass $param){
        //...
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj = $obj->actionWithParam(MyClass::PARAM_1);
```

Comment: You can't.  Also `MyClass $param` means `$params` must be an object of class `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an integer, not an instance of `MyClass`.

`MyClass::PARAM_1` is an integer, and that's what you're passing to `actionWithParam()`.  Since you've type-hinted that method, it requires it's argument be an "instance of" the MyClass class, which an integer clearly isn't.  Just take off that "MyClass" hinting and you shouldn't get that error anymore.

One has to ask though - why are you passing a class constant to a method in that very class?

Comment: _One has to ask though - why are you passing a class constant to a method in that very class?_ That's very common, why would you define them as global constants?  `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and many others.

Comment: I know that removed typeHint will works. I thought maybe there is way indicate which class constants need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your method definition typehints the parameter like this:

```
 public function actionWithParam(MyClass $param){
```

That means `$param` must be an instance of MyClass, but you're passing `MyClass::PARAM_1`, which is an integer. Just remove the typehint:

```
public function actionWithParam($param){
```

Or, you can typehint an integer parameter:

```
public function actionWithParam(int $param){
```

Also, you probably don't want to do this:

```
$obj = $obj->actionWithParam(MyClass::PARAM_1);
```

This will overwrite your `$obj` object instance with whatever value that method returns.